# Disk Space? (used/free/total) how do I get this? in C++

Tags: c++

Disk Space? (used/free/total) how do I get this? in C++...
thanks just for reading.

Comment: std::filesystem::space on C++17 "should" do the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937(VS.85).aspx) win32 API

Comment: There are cross-platform better solutions

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    struct statvfs fiData;

    if( argc < 2 ) {
            cout <<"Usage, ./size dir1 dir2 ... dirN\n";
            return(1);
    }

    //Lets loopyloop through the argvs
    for( int  i= 1 ; i<argc; i++ ) {
            if((statvfs(argv[i],&fiData)) < 0 ) {
                    cout << "\nFailed to stat:"  << argv[i];
            } else {
                    cout << "\nDisk: " <<  argv[i];
                    cout << "\nBlock size: "<< fiData.f_bsize;
                    cout << "\nTotal no blocks: "<< fiData.f_blocks;
                    cout << "\nFree blocks: "<< fiData.f_bfree;
            }
    }
}
```

**Compilation:** g++ -o size file.cpp

**Test:** ./size dir1 dir2

Comment: Use `fiData.f_bavail` in place for `fiData.f_bfree` for number of free blocks available to non-privileged process. This will help in calculating the more accurate free disk available.

Comment: Free block is always zero on newest Macs (Catalina)

Comment: @AdrianMaire how about `b_avail` on catalina?

Answer (score 6):

[statvfs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html) for linux.

Answer (score 2):

The original Linux statfs() and fstatfs() system calls were not designed with extremely large file sizes in mind. Subsequently, Linux 2.6 added new statfs64() and fstatfs64() system calls that employ a new structure, statfs64. The new structure contains the same fields as the original statfs structure, but the sizes of various fields are increased, to accommodate large file sizes.
see http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs64